# Oracle query not returning correct number of result

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

I have a java application which is fetching some records from the oracle database. The query is a simple one

```
select distinct * from table.
```

The issue is this query when run from the application does not return all the records. If there are 1000 records in the table then running this application returns different number of records every time. When the query is run directly using pl/sql developer it returns correct number of result.

Strange thing is that exact same code works fine with another Oracle server with exact same version of oracle database (it works fine for lot of other databases too) and the DBA has informed us that the data for both the servers is in sync.

I am not sure where to look for issues. The code does not look faulty. This issue is not reproducible in our lab. I tried to check alert logs but did not find anything. I think that there may be some process which is interfering when we are running the query from the application. Any pointers as to which logs can be analysed on oracle server which may point us in the right direction.

Will enabling audit or transaction logs be helpful?

Oracle version is 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit.

Comment: What number does a `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table` return from the application? Is the result the correct number?

Comment: Please insert the code you are using to run the query. Add relevant tags of library you may be using like "jdbc", "hibernate" etc.

Comment: Are different users seeing different numbers of results, but consistent numbers for each user? Maybe there's a VPD rule in place if so? The DBA would probably be aware of that though. (It's not entirely clear, but I'm assuming you're seeing this when the data is stable and everything is committed, not just different results as the data actually changes legitimately...)

Comment: @deHaar To find the count , query would have to be changed in the code which is not possible yet as it has been already deployed. CS_noob it is normal jdbc code but since there are many files involved it may not be possible for me to add the code here. Alex Poole we havent tried with different users but the results are correct when the query is run from pl/sql developer. Thank you for helping out on this.